# Clock replacement algorithm to be replaced with LRU in postgres 8.2.19 .Any ideas?

Tags: c, algorithm, postgresql

In the postgres code, the code related to this change is present in these places

```
~/src/backend/storage/buffer/buf_init.c
~/src/backend/storage/buffer/bufmgr.c
~/src/backend/storage/buffer/freelist.c
```

I tried to change my code in `freelist.c` which has the actual clock replacement algorithm logic.
Can some one please help me of how to proceed with replacing the clock replacement algorithm logic with LRU logic.
Related ideas are welcomed!
Thanks in advance.

here is a part of code of `freelist.c`

```
volatile BufferDesc *
StrategyGetBuffer(void)
{
    volatile BufferDesc *buf;
    int trycounter;
    LWLockAcquire(BufFreelistLock, LW_EXCLUSIVE);

    /*
     * Try to get a buffer from the freelist.  Note that the freeNext fields
     * are considered to be protected by the BufFreelistLock not the
     * individual buffer spinlocks, so it's OK to manipulate them without
     * holding the spinlock.
     */
    while (StrategyControl->firstFreeBuffer >= 0)
    {
        buf = &BufferDescriptors[StrategyControl->firstFreeBuffer];
        Assert(buf->freeNext != FREENEXT_NOT_IN_LIST);

        /* Unconditionally remove buffer from freelist */
        StrategyControl->firstFreeBuffer = buf->freeNext;
        buf->freeNext = FREENEXT_NOT_IN_LIST;

        /*
         * If the buffer is pinned or has a nonzero usage_count, we cannot use
         * it; discard it and retry.  (This can only happen if VACUUM put a
         * valid buffer in the freelist and then someone else used it before
         * we got to it.)
         */
        LockBufHdr(buf);
        if (buf->refcount == 0 && buf->usage_count == 0)
            return buf;
        UnlockBufHdr(buf);
    }
    /* Nothing on the freelist, so run the "clock sweep" algorithm */
    trycounter = NBuffers;
    for (;;)
    {
        buf = &BufferDescriptors[StrategyControl->nextVictimBuffer];

        if (++StrategyControl->nextVictimBuffer >= NBuffers)
            StrategyControl->nextVictimBuffer = 0;

        /*
         * If the buffer is pinned or has a nonzero usage_count, we cannot use
         * it; decrement the usage_count and keep scanning.
         */
        LockBufHdr(buf);
        if (buf->refcount == 0 && buf->usage_count == 0)
            return buf;
        if (buf->usage_count > 0)
        {
            buf->usage_count--;
            trycounter = NBuffers;
        }
        else if (--trycounter == 0)
        {
            /*
             * We've scanned all the buffers without making any state changes,
             * so all the buffers are pinned (or were when we looked at them).
             * We could hope that someone will free one eventually, but it's * probably  
               better to fail than to risk getting stuck in an
             * infinite loop.
             */
            UnlockBufHdr(buf);
            elog(ERROR, "no unpinned buffers available");
        }
        UnlockBufHdr(buf);
    }

    /* not reached */
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you doing anything to PostgreSQL 8.2? Go get a current version, there's no point wasting your time on something that obsolete. (Is this some kind of assignment?)